# Is it possible, on B2C, to set up dynamic error messages depending on the log in behavior?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

The cx needs to set up a dynamic response in the sign in policy, B2C, that depending on the scenario, a custom message is displayed / triggered. Specifically:

**I need to create new IDs with new message. Is it possible? Thanks.**

**ID    Default message Localized / customized message
UserMessageIfInvalidPassword    Your password is incorrect  
UserMessageCustomID1    Your trial has expired  
UserMessageCustomID2    No license aliable. Please contact support@...**

This is what the cx is trying, and have done already:

This actually is piece of code in the REST API (in PHP).  I defined the following ClaimsProvider which reference to that PHP file and then included it in the TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml file. I hope this information helps. Thank you.

So, it loops back to my question, I don't know how to display a custom error message either from a REST API call or with a predefined ID (e.g., a self-defined ID UserMessageNoEnoughLicense just like a predefined ID UserMessageIfInvalidPassword).

I'm referring to this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids.

Comment: Could you please update the content of your question so that is as short as possible and to the point.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of your RESTful API in your SISU policy/flow. Design the integration with the RESTful services in the following ways:

- **Validation technical profile:** The call to the RESTful service happens within a validation technical profile of the specified self-asserted technical profile, or a verification display control of a display control. The validation technical profile validates the user-provided data before the user journey moves forward. With the validation technical profile, you can:

  - Send claims to your REST API.
  - Validate claims, and throw custom error messages that are displayed to the user.
  - Send back claims from the REST API to subsequent orchestration steps.
- **Claims exchange:** A direct claims exchange can be configured by calling a REST API technical profile directly from an orchestration step of a user journey. This definition is limited to:

  - Send claims to your REST API.
  - Validate claims, and throw custom error messages that are returned to the application.
  - Send back claims from the REST API to subsequent orchestration steps.

*You can add a REST API call at any step in the user journey defined by a custom policy.* **For example**, you can call a REST API:

- **During sign-in**, just before Azure AD B2C validates the credentials.
- Immediately **after sign-in**.
- **Before Azure AD B2C** creates a new account in the directory.
- **After Azure AD B2C** creates a new account in the directory.
- **Before Azure AD B2C** issues an access token.

[image]

Then, use the error message response from the API to override the message IDs mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids).

**RESTful error messages can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids#restful-service-error-messages).**

You can visit this link for more information on how to implement it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-rest-api-intro#sending-data

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, very helpful.

I'm trying the 2nd approach (claim exchange) but I need some elaboration on the following statement:
Validate claims, and throw custom error messages that are returned to the application.
What exactly means by "throw custom error message that are returned to the application"? In my code you can see I already returned error code 409 and an custom error message. But I didn't see the error message or the error code anywhere in the application. It's not in the claims so where to find it? Thanks.

Best regards,

Comment: As mentioned in this line `use the error message response from the API to override the message IDs mentioned here.` pls refer the documentation on implementing the writing of error messages on custom UI.

Comment: I think this is for override the message content but not IDs, could you please help to confirm that? I have a video for you to explain what I want exactly. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ygpzrUxVG-A&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Screenshot:
https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&insightstoken=bcid_ToQ9drcwjOMB9g*ccid_hD12tzCM&form=ANCMS1&iss=SBIUPLOADGET&selectedindex=0&id=-1320626842&ccid=hD12tzCM&exph=407&expw=600&vt=2&sim=11